# correct pulse audio settings with RPI3 to decrease latency

Tags: pulse-audio

I'd like to send audio data by Ethernet to RPI3 but the sound is not great a lot of latency

Do you have a solution ?

I use OSMC

Comment: Thiis question seems to be very broad and is possibly not a good fit here :( https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Sending live audio over the network with low/no latency is *very* hard. But perhaps all you need is consistent latency?

Comment: I don't know i waited some settings for pulseaudio